# Linker error lnk2001 even though the unresolved symbol is defined

Tags: visual-c++, dll, linker, lnk2001

I have researched more into the problem and posted a more detailed question with my findings here: [Rust, how to use global variable from DLL? C++ equivalent requires __declspec(dllimport)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66181735/rust-how-to-use-global-variable-from-dll-c-equivalent-requires-declspecdl)

Original question:

#### Summary:

When linking my project with MSVC 2019's `link.exe`, I am getting errors such as `unresolved external symbol jl_module_type`. These symbols are defined in a file `julia.lib`, which I have verified using `dumpbin /exports julia.lib`. This file is passed as an argument to `link.exe`, and yet, it still complains about unresolved symbols. It looks like all the symbols that failed to be linked are variables rather than functions.

#### More information:

`julia.lib` has been renamed from `libjulia.dll.a`, and it corresponds to another file `libjulia.dll`. They were built with Cygwin/MinGW, but AFAIK this should not affect things. The actual project this is being used in is written in Rust, so `link.exe` is being invoked automatically by Rust's `cargo` tool. It is configured to build my project as a DLL.

Comment: Please provide a [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including pieces of code (how the function is defined, used), command outputs, and so on.

Comment: @CristiFati This question was caused by an odd tangle of tools that at the time I was unable to reduce, however, I have now figured out a much simpler example and posted a new question as much of this question is no longer relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66181735/rust-how-to-use-global-variable-from-dll-c-equivalent-requires-declspecdl